# sudo: node: command not find on EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, sudo

When run `sudo node --version` on EC2 Ubuntu, `error: sudo: node: command not find` appears.

I have read similar questions and answers published in stackoverflow, but no one works in myside...

my node js is in `/home/ubuntu/remoteserver/deviceServer.js`, when I run `sudo node deviceServer.js` in the directory remoteserver, error: `sudo: node: command not find` appears. It is the same when I run outside the directory...

when I run `whereis node`, I got:

```
node: /usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node
```

when I run `which npm`, I got:

```
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/npm
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Write nodejs instead of node.

Comment: same. sudo: nodejs: command not find

Answer (score -1):

It appears node in not in properties of root. But first of all, why do you need `sudo` to run node. You can directly do `node deviceServer.js`.

If you want compulsorily to use sudo. Execute below before running `sudo node`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node /usr/lib/node
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

Comment: thanks, because in my deviceServer.js, I need to open port 443. That needs sudo node to run. When I execute the code you commented, get error: ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/node': File exists

Comment: Try doing `sudo "$(which node)" deviceServer.js`. If it works, can you share output of `which node`?

Comment: @ Akki, get error ==> Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/remoteserver/deviceServer.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:596:3)

Comment: You should run this from path `/home/ubuntu/remoteserver/` or wherever your  ` deviceServer.js` file is located.

Comment: I did run this from path /home/ubuntu/remoteserver/